# ReactBootstrap.Modal not showing in Reagent application

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to use ReactBootstrap's Modal component in a Reagent application but get a "Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined" error when attempting to show the modal.

I have [cljsjs/react-bootstrap "0.28.1-1"] as a dependency in my project.

Here is the source that I used to test with:

```
(ns react-bootstrap-test.core
  (:require
    [reagent.core :as r]
    cljsjs.react-bootstrap))

(def rbutton (r/adapt-react-class js/ReactBootstrap.Button))
(def rmodal (r/adapt-react-class js/ReactBootstrap.Modal))
(def modal-header (r/adapt-react-class js/ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header))
(def modal-title (r/adapt-react-class js/ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title))
(def modal-body (r/adapt-react-class js/ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body))

(defonce show-modal (r/atom false))

(defn modal-test []
  [:div
   [rbutton {:bsStyle "primary"
             :bsSize "large"
             :active true
             :on-click (fn [e]
                         (reset! show-modal true)
                         (.stopPropagation e))}
    "Show Modal"]

   [:div.rmodal
    [rmodal {:show @show-modal}
     [modal-header
      [modal-title "Title"]]
     [modal-body
      [:h3 "Body"]]]]])

(r/render-component [modal-test]
                    (. js/document (getElementById "app")))
```